# How do I debug a Ruby Gem in a different directory in the context of a bundle in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rubygems

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to develop a Ruby gem.

To run the gem from the command line without installing it first I am using:

```
bundle exec my_gem
```

This works fine.

I can also create a `Gem Command` run configuration within IntelliJ IDEA and that works.

What I actually want to do is to run this gem in another directory.

Using bundler:

```
bundle exec --gemfile /path/to/my_gem my_gem
```

However from IntelliJ IDEA can't get this to work as there is no way to specify the path to the Gemfile. It fails saying:

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

Anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Just to be sure, does that directory reside in the project?

Comment: No it doesn't. Does that make a difference?

Comment: That was for understanding your structure. Have you tried setting this path in the bundler config file?